# Paid access subscription to a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint, web-applications

We have a SharePoint site and we now want to only allow users that have registered and paid to have access to the site by yearly subscription.

We would like to automate the process of managing the subscriptions and creating the users as much as possible.

I understand we will not get a turnkey solution. However, does the SO Community have any ideas on how we could do this. We will be using forms authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codeplex project [SharePoint 2007 List Membership Provider](http://splistmp.codeplex.com/)  allows you to maintain your users in a SharePoint list

Answer (score 2):

A bit more info would be welcome, but I'll give it a try. 
I assume you are running with FormsBasedAuthentication? If so, you would need to write the logic that creates the user in the database. The existing ASP.NET Membership Provider should meet all your needs. After that, you would need to add the newly created user to the appropriate sharepoint groups (this can also be done using the sharepoint object model).

The first step though would be to create your "become a member" page and make that accessible anonymously. Add a webpart / control to that page that handles the payment and then when succesful creates the ASP.NET Membership Provider user. Then adds that user to the appropriate sp groups. The easiest way to restict access would be to create a subsite of the main welcome site (root of the sitecollection), which has it's own rights and groups. make the root site accessible for anyone, allow access to the subsite for paying users only.

Comment: but how would we collect the money?

Comment: Use PayPal? Or get a merchant account to process credit cards. All major payment handlers out there have an API that will send you the result of a transaction (failed = user doesn't get access, success, user gets access to paid part of site)

Comment: And in Paypal just define your lengths of subscription (half a year, a year, etc. as products people can buy).